# Exported jar file not working properly. Which created using eclipse

Tags: java, user-interface, jar, executable-jar

This is how I created the jar file:

[image]

And the malfunction part is:

I clicked the log button but instead of viewing the panel, it shows the blank area.

[image]

Whereas the project works perfectly in ide(eclipse):

I clicked the log button in while launching using the ide.
(it's perfect!!)
[image]

What/how can I do to make it work perfectly as an executable jar file?

The thing is everything is working properly while using inside the ide.
But when I export it to a runnable jar file everything starts to messes up.

Comment: Can you include more detail on what the error is? At least to me, the gif cannot be paused and it doesn't show your interaction with the *.jar file, so it's kind hard to follow.

Comment: I edited the question pls update if u need any further details